# Why Energy varies linearly in case of graphene and other Weyl semi-metals and not in conventional semi-metals?

Tags: condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics, material-science, weyl-semimetal

The Energy-Momentum diagram in case of graphene is very unusual as it is conical in shape instead of paraboloid. This means that $E=\mathrm{E}_{0}^{}+ (\hbar^{2} k^{2}/2m)$ is not followed by Weyl semimetals. I searched and came to know about the concept of Dirac cones but I am not able to understand the underlying physics.